# One Drive API returns invalid Access Token

Tags: onedrive

The authentication process is not working now.(It was working earlier). By following the documentation I'm trying to get the access token from a refresh token. I successfully can get a access token. But it's not valid. I'm setting it as Bearer and send it in my GET request and it returns the following JSON

```
{"error":{"code":"accessDenied","message":"Access Denied"}}
```

Here is the code sample

```
    String messageBody = "client_id=" + "9b1a6dbb-7e1f-41b5-b448-9f328169411e" + "&redirect_uri=" + returnURL + "&client_secret={cleindsecret}
            + "&refresh_token={refreshtoken}&grant_type=refresh_token";

    RequestBody oAuthCodeRedeemBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
            messageBody);

    Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf")
            .post(oAuthCodeRedeemBody).build();

    String responseBody = null;
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setFollowRedirects(false);
    Response response;      

    String accessToken = null;

    try {
        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        responseBody = response.body().string();
        resp = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(responseBody);
    } catch (IOException | ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    accessToken = (String) resp.get("access_token");
```

I'm getting a Access Token here. But I can't use it to do any work.

```
Request request2 = new Request.Builder().url("https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/items/1ED8983F38E94F01!107/children").header("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken).get().build();
```

The response for the above code is returned as

```
{"error":{"code":"accessDenied","message":"Access Denied"}}
```

What is the reason here. Is the API returning me a invalid access token or is something wrong in my code?